# Those / These / They

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

Here is a piece of the text I'm writing now:

> The region was populated by Indigenous Australians who managed to preserve their traditional crafts. **They** / **Those** / **These** included ceramics, leather making, and dying of fabrics.

What pronoun should I use to refer to the word "crafts" in the previous sentence?

Comment: I think its "include" not "included"

Comment: Why? It's talking about the past - 'was populated'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> The region was populated by Indigenous Australians who managed to preserve their traditional crafts. These include ceramics, leather making, and dying of fabrics.

You cannot use "they", as the pronoun is supposed to refer to the "crafts", and "they" is referring to people. You also cannot use "those", as it is a plural version of "that", whereas "these" refer to items close by.

E.g.

> We use *this* and *these* most commonly to point to things and people that are close to the speaker or writer, or things that are happening now

Therefore, in this context, you should use "these"

For more information of "this/these/that/those" go to [this Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/this-that-these-those)

Comment: I agree with your answer in general, but *they* doesn't necessarily refer to people.  You could say, for example, "There are five houses in the village; *they* are small and unpainted."

Comment: _They_ would be ambiguous because it _could_ seem to refer to the indigenous Australians. _These_ makes it clear that it means the last-mentioned thing - the crafts.

Comment: Part of your answer depends on what you mean by "close," but that meaning is entirely unclear. Australians and their crafts are equally close or distant to most of us—in my case, about 12,000 km. But that's not really what you mean, right?